# What is the simplest way to divide a variable in SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I would like to divide a SASS variable (which is a map value) by two, as follows:

```
$grid-gutter-widths: (
  xs:  30px,
  sm:  30px
  ...
);

$col-padding-xs:  #{map-get($grid-gutter-widths, xs)/2}; // returns 15px

div {
  padding-right: $col-padding-xs / 2; // returns 15px/2
}
```

Unfortunately I was expecting `padding-right` value to be `7.5px` however it doesn't perform the division and instead returns a string with the slash in the middle. However this seems to work:

```
$col-padding-xs: 15px;

div {
  padding-right: $col-padding-xs / 2; // returns 7.5px
}
```

So the map value must be the wrong type. Is there an easy way to cast it as a number so I can perform simple math on it in SASS?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are already dividing it by two in your getter, I am having a hard time understanding your question. The simplest way is to use a dash and the number you want it divided by.

Comment: @Sqnkov Sorry, it's a bit confusing; 30px is divided by two in the getter, and I wish to divide the result (15px) by two again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. It's a matter of the interpolation on the map-get that you have to remove. You can see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZZjrJ) for the compiled css.

```
$grid-gutter-widths: (
  xs:  30px,
  sm:  30px
);

$col-padding-xs:  map-get($grid-gutter-widths, xs) / 2; // returns 15px

div {
  padding-right: $col-padding-xs / 2; // returns 7.5px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new SASS version math.div takes the place instead of the divider symbol(/).
e.g. $col-padding-xs:  #{map-get(math.div($grid-gutter-widths, xs), 2)};

It uses two numbers and divide them.

Source: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div